# Is it necessary to cover the top in a pond with silver arowana?

Tags: aquarium, fish, pond

I have a 400 gallon (1500 L) pond with two oscars, two tinfoil barbs and a 10" silver arowana. I've had this arowana for like 2 months and it hasn't try to jump out, yet.

It has plenty of room to swim around ( around 3 sqm) and if it want to jump out, it is possible to do so since water is few inches below the edge.

Please tell me if I still need to cover the pond with a net in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Arowanas are notorious for jumping and in the wild will often [jump out of water to catch some small insects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_arowana#Description) or other prey. It's probably less likely when they're in a pond because there is nothing to spook them at the sides like there could be in a fish tank. Props to you for ensuring that it is in a reasonably sized pond.

Based on the average cost of an Arowana and their propensity to jump for prey (both based on their environment and nature), I wouldn't hesitate to put a net over the top. One only needs to do a quick Google search for 'Arowana Jumping' to see examples of the fish jumping both in captivity and the wild and the last thing you want to find is the fish outside the pond.

Comment: thanks , yes as you said he jumped out yesterday and then jumped back in to the pond , yes I will add a net soon , till then I added a 1 ft layer of dwarf lettuce all around the pond where it can jump out , now he cant go to the edges because of the roots of lettuce , but will add a net soon

Answer (score 0):

I think you are more likely to need protection for the fish from raccoons, wading birds, snakes, etc , than jumping out.